# User input function keep looping until valid filename entered

Tags: python, beginner, validation, file

The following function is basically asking the user to input a file name for a file that the calling program is going to do something with.  If the user enters an invalid file name, I want the program to loop back and give them another chance.  The code works, but is this the proper way to accomplish this?  Also, are there other errors that could get triggered that I should deal with?

```
def get_filename(file_type):
    while True:
        print('enter ' + file_type + ' filename: ')
        filename = input()
        print(filename)
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                my_file = f.read()
            return my_file
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('No such file.  Check file name and path and try again.')


x = get_filename('TEMPLATE')
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

> is this the proper way to accomplish this?

Yes; looping is the best approach for this type of functionality (see e.g. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761)).

---

> are there other errors that could get triggered that I should deal with?

There are reasons *other than* not finding the file that `open`ing and `read`ing the file could fail; in this case, I would probably catch the more general [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) to handle all of these. I would also restructure slightly to minimise the code in the `try` block:

```
try:
    with open(filename) as f:  # note that 'r' is the default mode
        my_file = f.read()
except OSError:
    print('Error accessing file. Check file name and path and try again.')
else:
    return my_file
```

---

A few other minor notes:

- You should consider adding a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), explaining what the function does and how to use it;
- Currently, the `file_type` is **only** used for display purposes - consider adding checks that the user has selected an appropriate file;
- Returning the string content of the file means you have to read the whole thing into memory up-front, which may not be ideal with larger files; and
- I would use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) rather than `+` concatenation, and just pass the text straight to `input` as the `prompt` argument rather than having a separate `print` call.

Comment: Thanks @jon.  concerning "read the whole thing into memory up-front"  is there a better method?  am I better off just reopening the file later in my program?

Comment: for the string format, is it acceptabe to just say: `print('enter %s filename' % file_type)`?

Comment: @ChristopherPearson it depends what you're doing with the file. If you want to handle large files, I would suggest using `os.path.isfile` to check it in `get_filename`, and returning only the valid filename. Then you can open the file and iterate over it line-by-line at the appropriate point. On string formatting, I see `%` as somewhat old-fashioned/unpythonic vs. `str.format`, but it's not actually deprecated.

Comment: Is this the correct usage?: `filename = input('enter {!s} filename: '.format(file_type))`

Comment: @ChristopherPearson have you tried it; does it do what you want?

Comment: yes, sorry it does.  I was just making sure it was the proper way.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ChristopherPearson yep, that's how I'd have done it!

Comment: Your version reports "No such file" when, say, a permission problem is encountered. I would consider the original code to be better — at least it's more honest.

Comment: @200_success that's a fair point, but perhaps more a problem of retaining the original error message than the functionality *per se*. Updated.